# How to redirect Joomla to a HTML page?

Tags: redirect, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla website that contains a menu with some items, i want when pressing an item of that menu to be redirected to a HTML page somewhere is my pc, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new menu item

select menu item type: External URL

fill menu title

and fill link with your html page location and save

[image]

**UPDATE:**

if you install joomla in your wamp localhost

copy menu.html file in your joomla directory

wamp www directory : ( c:\wamp\www\joomla directory name)

then link in menu item : `http://localhost/joomla directory name /menu.html`

Comment: it gives me "Save not permitted"

Comment: is your link : javascript:void() ?

Comment: replace your directory location with :  file:///C:/Users/Muhammed Refaat/Desktop/cafe/rock_cafe2/menu.html

Comment: i can't understand you, but it's a regular directory (C:\Users\Muhammed Refaat\Desktop\cafe\rock_cafe2\menu.html) , the menu.html contains html with js and jquery code

Comment: replace your directory location with : file:///C:/Users/Muhammed Refaat/Desktop/cafe/rock_cafe2/menu.html

Comment: Now it's saved successfully but when clicking the item in the website it don't make any response and not going anywhere

Comment: why dont upload your html file on server?

Comment: on my local server? i'm using wamp, and i installed my Joomla website into it, so, what is the best place to upload it, and then i'll make the same operation but just change the directory?

Comment: i update my answer , please give more information when you ask a question